# Can I count rows and get a column value at the same time with SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using a `SELECT COUNT(*)` in order to verify that a user exists with PHP PDO and MySQL. I'd also like to get a specific column value. There is only ever one value/row or no value/row per user.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AND column FROM table WHERE user=:user');
```

What I'm hoping to get back is, 1, and the column value. Where I can then bind the column value to a variable.

If not, I'll have to first do the `SELECT COUNT(*)` then do another query to get the column name after verifying that the user and this column exists from the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query.

Comment: Why not just select the column and see how many rows are returned?

Comment: @Graeme I have no reason not to, I'm trying to "optimize" and you might have just helped me do that, let me try that.

Comment: Hope so :)  Either count the number of rows or check for a null value (assuming null isn't a valid value for that column obviously :) )  `empty` is probably a good test to make too

Answer (score 0):

You just need to think a little.

"count(*)" is not a special method "to verify that a user exists". It's just a query where you select count because you just have no idea what to select else.

But as long as you have a column to select, you don't need no counts anymore.

Therefore, just select your value, and as long as you are getting it, you can tell that a user exists

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT column FROM table WHERE user=:user');
$stmt->execute([$user]);
$col = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($col) {
    // user exists
    $something = $col; // use $col as you wanted
}
```

While selecting count() and a column without a group by operator is a tricky query, and you should avoid it in general.

Comment: I verify that the user exists or this row exists because of the WHERE user=:user clause

Comment: Your method is cleaner, I will try it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work. I don't know if the line $stmt->execute([$user]); is still equivalent to bindParam for prevention of injection. Aside from that, I still tried it and was not able to echo out a row or "column"

Comment: It's normal. We all learning and not every time we get things smooth first time. You have to try harder.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT count(*), column FROM table where user=:user
```

It's what you want no ?

Otherwise you can count the number of result in php

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=XXX.fr.mysql;dbname=YYYY', 'ZZZ', 'TTT', $pdo_options);

    $response = $pdo->query('SELECT column FROM table');
    $count = 0;
    while ($data = $response->fetch())
    {
        $count++;
    }
    $reponse->closeCursor();
```

Comment: I'm not sure, is that "SQL legal" ? I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: You also can use an alias for your count. Select count(*) as total, column from table etc. It's works I think